# Using an object property as a parameter in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters, redundancy

I have a depth first search algorithm that is pulling information from an Ontology.

I have a working function to get all of the objects with a particular property, however, I essentially need to do the same thing for a different property.

If I have these two simplified functions for example

```
def a():
    for n in nodes:
        do something with n.property1

def b():
    for n in nodes:
        do something with n.property2
```

Is there a way that I can pass the desired property in as a parameter? So that I end up with:

```
def a(property):
    for n in nodes:
        do something with n.property

a(property1)
a(property2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, yes. `getattr()` is a built-in function that allows you to get a property from an object based on its name. `setattr()` also exists, and can be used to assign a value to a property from an object based on the property's name.

```
def a(propertyname):  # pass property name as a string
    for n in nodes:
        do something with getattr(n, propertyname)

a('property1')
a('property2')
```

However, this is generally considered a bit risky, and it's probably better to structure your code in such a way that it's not necessary. It might be possible, for example, to use lambdas instead:

```
def a(getter):
    # pass a function that returns the value of the relevant parameter
    for n in nodes:
        do something with getter()

a(lambda n:n.property1)
b(lambda n:n.property2)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this is considered risky?

Comment: @SeanPayne mostly because it makes it easier to mess with your objects unintentionally (e.g. by changing the variable passed to it arbitrarily), but also because it's a little more difficult for static code tools to understand than the usual `obj.property` syntax. Not necessarily _bad_ (and I was wrong to put as such in my answer, I'll change that), but you should definitely know what you're doing before using `getattr()` lest it lead to mistakes that are hard to debug.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I will use it as there is very low risk of having these types of problems in the project I'm currently working on.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
def a(property):
   ...
   print(getattr(n, property))
```

and call this method with string parameters:

```
a("property1")
a("property2")
```